# iOS multiplayer game - Game Center and Facebook Connect

Tags: ios, facebook, ipad, game-center

I am planning to develop an iOS multiplayer game. I plan to use Game Center. How does this work if I want to also have facebook connect? Is it either/or? Is it simple to use them both concurrently?

Comment: I'd love to hear about this. I also want to implement Facebook connect for multiplayer but can't find any sources about it. Does FB handle the connection and data transfers in this case or is it just used to point the devices to a remote server? Can you direct me if you have any knowledge or sources to how this would be implemented?

Answer (score 0):

It's not either-or.  You can use as many 3rd-party social networks as you want in your game.  Game Center provides a transport mechanism for sending game data to all the participants of your game, which Facebook Connect does not.  Facebook Connect only gives you the ability to list your player's FB friends, not the ability to initiate games with them.

Comment: are you sure that you cannot initiate new games with your fb friends? it seems to me that when I play draw something or words with friends I do use the facebook connect feature to initiate games with friends.

Comment: @LucyWeatherford I'm pretty sure neither words nor draw something uses game center.